# How to find a Shelveset using information provided by a CodeReviewRequest

Tags: c#, tfs, tfs-workitem, tfs-sdk, shelveset

If I have the name and the owner of the Shelveset, I can find it successfully using the following code:

```
 foreach (Shelveset shelveset in
     versionControlServer.QueryShelvesets(workItem.
         Fields["Associated Context"].Value.ToString(), "NW\\LFreeman"))
```

where `workItem` is an instance of a `CodeReviewRequest` `workItem`.

I can get the name of the `CodeReviewRequest` from `workItem.Fields["Associated Context"]`

If I set the owner to `null` as such, it returns an empty list.  It has been reported to me that this method will only work when the owner is specified as a string.

I am trying to figure out how to get the owner.

Using `workItem.Fields["Associated Context Owner"].Value.ToString()`, I am able to get the GUID of the owner.

The challenge is now how to convert the GUID to the expected owner which would be "NW\LFreeman".

When I print out the `workItems.Fields["Associated Context Owner"].Value.ToString()`, here's what I see:

```
c3741a78-1a44-4bf6-95b0-f360cd387f3e
```

Is it possible to retrieve "NW\LFreeman" from this GUID?  If so, what method call will enable me to do this mapping?

---

Edit:

Here is the code that worked for me based on the answer and link given:

```
Guid ownerId = new Guid(codeReviewRequestWorkItem.Fields["Associated Context Owner"].Value.ToString());

Guid[] teamFoundationIds = new Guid[1];
teamFoundationIds[0] = ownerId;

TeamFoundationIdentity[] users = ims.ReadIdentities((Guid[])teamFoundationIds, MembershipQuery.None);

Shelveset[] shelves = vcs.QueryShelvesets(codeReviewRequestWorkItem.Fields["Associated Context"].Value.ToString(), users[0].UniqueName.ToString());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`IIdentityManagementService.ReadIdentities`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff731923(v=vs.120).aspx) is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks!  That solved the issue.  I will add the details to the question.